# Can I use Matlab Coder generating .Net dll for C# project?

Tags: c#, matlab, dll

I have a calculation algorithm in Matlab, and I want to use that algorithm in my C# project.
I plan to convert this MatLab code to a .net dll, but I do not want to install the MatLab runtime.

Can I use Matlab Coder generating a .Net dll?

I know MatLab library compiler can generate .Net .dll, but it needs MatLab runtime to run the dll.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Eric

PS: I use Matlab Coder generating C codes from the MatLab project.
But I need .net .dll for my C# project

Comment: You do not need to install the runtime if the same version of Matlab exists on the computer where you are running (including license).   The runtime is part of the regular matlab release.  The runtime does not need a license to run.

Comment: **No**. The matlab coder only generate `C` source code. The matlab compiler does not generate source code. Your only option is to translate the algorithm yourself, from `MATLAB` to `C#`, or from the `C` generated code to `C#`.